# Why does an Entity need to be serializable when using shared primary key in JPA 2/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, serializable

So I have the following situation:

```
@Entity
class Image {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  ....
}

@Entity
class ImageData implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @OneToOne
  private Image image;

  ....
}
```

This is all working fine, but why does ImageData need to be serializable? If it's not I get Exceptions that it needs to be serializable:

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: composite-id class must implement Serializable:...
```

I know Identifier need to be serializable but why is it now the other way around?

Comment: That's strange - I was under the impression that *all* JPA entity classes need to be Serializable.

Comment: if you don't have anything hibernate-specific, could you try, for a test, to replace it with eclipselink and see if this behaviour is consistent. If not - raise an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why composite-id class must implement Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about a similar topic on the Hibernate forums that should answer your question, have a look [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2306165&sid=857145b56a9e06c8fa10aca8199c7312)

Comment: ok they are also saying that the class with the composite-id needs to be serializable but not why...