# In Hibernate for composite-id, why the class should implement Serializable

Tags: java, hibernate

The hibernate document says that the class that we use for composite-id should implement serializable, here is the document link that I am going through: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid

> The persistent class must override equals() and hashCode() to
>   implement composite identifier equality. It must also implement
>   Serializable.

But why it is required to implement serializable?

I have gone through this SO link: [Why composite-id class must implement Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable)

but I am not understanding the answer given there, please help me in understanding the concept here.

Answer (score 2):

Because hibernate uses a cache which can store individual values, ids especially.  for non-primitive classes, there needs to be a way to convert those individual values into bytes for transport and storage in the cache.  the mechanism that hibernate uses for non-primitive classes is java serialization.