# Hibernate composed entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I may be mixing up terms, but what I call a simple entity is something like `Customer` or `Product`, i.e., a thing having its own identity and for which I'm using an `Integer id`.

A composed entity is something like `CustomerProduct`, allowing to create an m:n mapping and associate some data with it. I created

```
class CustomerProduct extends MyCompositeEntity {
    @Id @ManyToOne private Customer;
    @Id @ManyToOne private Product;
    private String someString;
    private int someInt;
}
```

and I'm getting the message

> Composite-id class must implement Serializable

which lead me directly to these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609715/in-hibernate-for-composite-id-why-the-class-should-implement-serializable) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable). I trivially could implement `Serializable`, but this would mean to serialize `Customer` and `Product` as a part of `CustomerProduct` and this makes no sense to me. What I'd need is a composite key containing two `Integer`s, just like a normal key is just one `Integer`.

*Am I off the track?*

If not, how can I specify this using just annotations (and/or code)?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate session objects need to be serializable, this implies all referenced objects must be serializable too. Even if your were using primitive types as a composite key, you need to add a serialization step.

You can use a composite primary key in Hibernate with the annotations `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`.

With `IdClass` you can do the follwing (assuming your entities use integer keys):

```
public class CustomerProduckKey implements Serializable {
    private int customerId;
    private int productId;

    // constructor, getters and setters
    // hashCode and equals
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CustomerProduckKey.class)
class CustomerProduct extends MyCompositeEntity { // MyCompositeEntity implements Serializable
    @Id private int customerId;
    @Id private int productId;

    private String someString;
    private int someInt;
}
```

You primary key class must be public and must have a public no-args constructor. It also must be `serializable`.

You can also use `@EmbeddedId` and `@Embeddable`, which is a bit clearer and allows you to reuse the PK elsewhere.

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerProduckKey implements Serializable {
    private int customerId;
    private int productId;
    //...
}

@Entity
class CustomerProduct extends MyCompositeEntity {
    @EmbeddedId CustomerProduckKey customerProductKey;

    private String someString;
    private int someInt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@EmbeddedId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) and [`@MapsId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html):

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerProductPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer customerId;
    private Integer productId;
    //...
}

@Entity
class CustomerProduct {
    @EmbeddedId
    CustomerProductPK customerProductPK;

    @MapsId("customerId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer;

    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Product;

    private String someString;
    private int someInt;
}
```