# Implementing Serializable interface in hibernate entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, serializable

What is the use of implementing `Serializable` interface in hibernate entity class?
That interface continue nothing in that.

Answer (score 3):

It's [Marker Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and  just  like an normal `interface.`

> The marker interface pattern is a design pattern in computer science, used with languages that provide run-time type information about objects. It provides a means to associate metadata with a class where the language does not have explicit support for such metadata.

In `Serializable` case java

```
public interface Serializable{
}
```

and some class

```
 public class someObje  implements Serializable{

  }
```

And somewhere else `Runtime` realizes objects like

```
 if(someObje instnaceOf Serializable){

  //Hey this object can serialize you know. Grant security permission.

 }
```

Coming to your question, by definition

> **Serialization** where an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as information about the object's type and the types of data stored in the object.

Now without **Serialization** ,how hibernate entities move in your application (`Client <=> Server <=> Database)`?

And also to detect the type. For ex in hibernate look at the method signature of Seesion#get()  method

```
Object get(Class clazz,
           **Serializable** id)
           throws HibernateException
```

Note:This theory applies not only for hibernate entities where ever `Object` needs to be serialize.

Comment: why would  hibernate entities inned to be `Serializable ` move your application ?

Comment: For example, Client <=> Server, since they are the domain object ?? And a little edit on my post too.

Comment: I understand that. My query was specific to  hibernate related operations.

Comment: Consider a small example : Without serialization, how can Domain objects `Id`  `ex :(setId(long))`  Is saving as a primary key in your database ??  If your object is not Serializable, java won't give that information to underlying database.

Comment: Well, that's true [about the keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable) (primary, composite) but not the entities in general.

Comment: @Suresh Hibernate in turn fires SQL queries. `setId(long);` doesn't mean that the object is serialized and stored somewhere. It will eventually lead to an `update` statement getting fired, thereby storing the Id value in DB table.

Answer (score 2):

- Not sure why  in Hibernate entity classes need to implement `Serializable` interface. A `Serializable` POJO is the one which can be **written to the disc** or **transmitted over the wire**.
- If your Hibernate entities or POJOs are involved in any of these then only you need to  implement `Serializable` interface.

EDIT:
- Just realized that the keys (primary, composite) needs to be `Serializable` as they are referred by persistent `Session`. ([Reference](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2306165&sid=857145b56a9e06c8fa10aca8199c7312))