# "Not known whether passed class name ... is safe" using JPA EmbeddedId with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

In a very distilled version of the sample code available from a tutorial, [Embedded Compound Primary Key : Primary Key « JPA « Java Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EmbeddedCompoundPrimaryKey.htm), I'm getting:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: unit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at [my code that calls e.persist on a Student]
```

The exception is fairly generic, but Hibernate provides some good log debug info (I've replaced the actual package name with <package>):

```
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl: Not known whether passed class name [<package>.Student] is safe
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl: No temp ClassLoader provided; using live ClassLoader for loading potentially unsafe class : <package>.Student
```

Here's the distilled code.  (The backstory is that I'd been trying, to no avail, to create an entity with an embedded id.  After a while of trying to debug that, I re-started with this tutorial code, removing things until I got the same error.)

```
@Embeddable
class StudentId {
    private int id; 

    public StudentId() {}
    
    public StudentId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        return ((o instanceof StudentId) && id == ((StudentId) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return id; }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentId id;
    
    public Student() {}
    
    public Student(int id) { this.id = new StudentId(id); }
}
```

Comment: I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32852596/1281433) to this that worked for me, but I'd be happy to have a more authoritative answer that explains the underlying issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The embeddable class needs to be serializable.  Updating the definition of StudentId to implement Serializable (and adding a serialVersionUID), the issue seems to disappear:

```
@Embeddable
class StudentId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7415410969017941320L;

    // ...
}
```

Once I discovered this, I was able to do a bit more research, but it was of varying degrees of helpfulness.  For instance, [Do Hibernate table classes need to be Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2726300/1281433), discusses whether *entity* classes need to be Serializable.  In general, they don't.  Another question, [Why composite-id class must implement Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9271835/1281433), is more relevant, but making the id class non-serializable there produces a different error message than what I was getting.

User OndrejM,  in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852595/not-known-whether-passed-class-name-is-safe-using-jpa-embeddedid-with-hibe/32852596?noredirect=1#comment53566959_32852596), pointed out [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588400/1281433) to [How to map a composite key with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585034/1281433) that locates the part of the JPA 1.0 specification that dictates that composite key classes must be serializable.  For completeness, the relevant portion from the later spec, [JSR-000338 Java<sup>TM</sup> Persistence 2.1 Final Release for Evaluation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html), is:

> #### 2.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> … The following rules apply for composite primary keys: …
>
> - The primary key class must be serializable.

Comment: Generally, entity class **DO NOT** need to be serializable, it is required only when they need to be passed to remote systems via RMI (calling a remote EJB). However, the JPA specification explicitely requires compound keys to be serializable, for a reason unknown to me. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate#answer-3588400) for more info.

Comment: @ Joshua Taylor I was happy to help. Adding the answer from my comment is fine, lets leave it that way.