# JPA 2 - How to build entity that has Primary key that is also a foreign key using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Given the following tables:

```
Car
int id PK
int modelId FK

CarDetails
int carId PK, FK to Car.id
varchar(50) description
```

How would I indicate that the `@Id` of `CarDetails` is also a foreign key to `Car`?

I've tried:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "modelId", nullable = false)
    private Model model;

    //setters & getters
}

@Entity
public class CarDetails {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId", nullable = false)
    private Car car;

    private String description;

    //setters & getters
}
```

However, I get the error

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.example.CarDetails`

After implementing `Serializable` I get `This class [class com.example.CarDetails] does not define an IdClass`. But I still get the error after adding `@IdClass(Car.class)` to the `CarDetails` class.

**UPDATE**

The `IdClass` error originates from Spring:
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carDetailsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.example.CarDetails] does not define an IdClass`

Here's the CarDetailsRepository:

```
public interface CarDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<CarDetails, Car> {

}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.3.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {

    pmd group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-tools', version: '5.2.3.Final'
    pmd group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
    pmd group: 'org.hibernate.common', name: 'hibernate-commons-annotations', version: '5.0.1.Final'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.2.10.Final')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final')
    compile('org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final')
    runtime('net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1')
    runtime('com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:4.2')
    runtime('javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.4.RELEASE') }
}
```

Comment: Your mapping seems OK. Are you sure you're using JPA 2?

Comment: Implement Serializable?

Comment: @crizzis - I'm using hibernate 5 which I believe is a JPA 2 implementation.

Comment: @Rossi - not sure I understand the question. I'm receiving an error that states that I must implement `Serializable` if I don't do such.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable

Comment: @RossiRobinsion, how is that thread related? `CarDetails` is **not** a composite-id entity

Comment: @James, I've tried your code and got the same error, but it went away after making `CarDetails` implement `Serializable`...

Comment: @crizzis - Thanks. The exception `This class [class com.example.CarDetails] does not define an IdClass` is originating from Spring during bean creating `Error creating bean with name 'carDetailsRepository'`.  So it appears that Spring Data JPA is requiring the IdClass. But even if you add the annotation, Spring still complains. After more research, I just found it is a bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-866.

Comment: I have a question. So what is correct? `extends JpaRepository<CarDetails, Car>` or `extends JpaRepository<CarDetails, Integer>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best way is to reference `carId` twice in your `CarDetails` entity--once for the @Id and once for the foreign key reference. You must declare one of these references with `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` so that JPA doesn't get confused trying to manage the same column in two spots:

```
@Entity
public class CarDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "carId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int carId; // don't bother with getter/setter since the `car` reference handles everything

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId", nullable = false)
    private Car car;

    private String description;

    //setters & getters
}
```

It looks odd, but it'll work and it's actually the (most) preferred method.

Comment: I should mention that the reason this is the preferred method is because it's the form you'll need to use anyway if your second entity's ID is a composite key made up of the IDs of two (or more) different entities, and you want foreign key references to those entities. So to keep things consistent just always use this form.

Comment: Thanks. This works well in my example where `carId` is an `int`. However, if `carId` was changed to `String`, I would have to manually set a non-null value prior to saving the entity. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown. Don't have to set it with `int` because it has a default value (i.e. 0).

Comment: If `carId` is a String, then `car.id` must also be a String. It still works. Have faith!  :)

Comment: In other words, you don't have to set `carId` to anything at all (hence no getters or setters). You ignore `carId` in your code and just use the `car` reference. If you want to get the car ID you use `getCar().getId()` just like you would have if `carId` weren't there.

Comment: Agreed; `car.id` must also be a String in that case. I tried it with both `carId` and `car.id` being `String` and I get `Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`.

Comment: @James that's a separate issue. You can't use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on a String. You can only use it on numbers.

Comment: In other words, JPA only knows how to automatically assign an ID to a new entity if the ID is a number type (int, long, Long, etc). If the ID is a String you must manually set the new entity's ID before attempting to save it (and get rid of the line I mentioned above).

Comment: Interesting... I removed that annotation. Not sure why it is complaining... The originating exception is `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.example.CarDetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`

Comment: @James: Yeah, before you can save an entity whose ID isn't automatically generated you must assign an ID to it. For example, `car.setId("foo");`

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. So, in the `String` scenario a bit of manual duplication to maintain.

Comment: Sorry... I misread your comment. I get an exception if only call `carDetails.set(car)` where car already has its id set. I have to call `carDetails.setId("foo");` in order for this to work.

Comment: @James you should never have to call `CarDetails.setId`.  When you create a new Car, and if `car.id` is a String, you will need to call `Car.setId` on it. But when you create a new CarDetails, you just need to call `CarDetails.setCar` on it, regardless of whether `car.id` is a String.

Comment: Makes sense. I would do exactly that but I get the exception unless I explicitly set the id on CarDetails. Do you get the exception when you try? Have you tried doing this with a Spring Repository? I did find a Spring JPA Data bug that appears to be related https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-866.

Comment: If you’re getting an exception in that scenario, make sure you have the `insertable = false...` line mentioned above.

Comment: I have `insertable = false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147762/discussion-between-james-and-alvin-thompson).

Comment: Actually, in that scenario you’re right–you’ll need to set it in both places. I forgot to add, in the definition of `CarDetails.setCar(Car newCar)` you may want to optionally add `carId = newCar.getId();` (with null checks of course) to avoid having to manually do this.

Comment: That applies regardless of the type of `car.id`. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks. That will work. Another option is to change my database schema such that `CarDetails` has two separate cols for FK and PK. So one col for FK back to the `Car` and another col that is a PK auto generating `id`.

Comment: i strongly recommend against doing that. you’re breaking normalization on your database. what do you do if the columns wind up with two different values?

Comment: I would put a unique constraint on the FK (`CarDetails.carId`) so that two rows in `CarDetails` cannot refer to the same carId.

Comment: Thanks for covering the additional scenario of a String being the PK and FK. I plan to upvote & accept your answer. I do think another viable option is to add an auto gen `id` to `CarDetails` and put the unique constraint on the FK (`CarDetails.carId`). Would appreciate your thoughts of doing that with the unique constraint vs adding the extra code in the setter.

Comment: @James That would work, but I would argue that you're not reducing complexity; you're just moving it from JPA to the DB (since you have to add a column). What's worse, insertions will be much slower (now there are **2** indexes and the DB has to produce a new autoincrement ID for each insert).

Comment: It did not wrok for me without @MapsId

Answer (score 2):

You might try mapping `CarDetails` like this:

```
@Entity
public class CarDetails {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId", nullable = false)
    private Car car;

    private String description;

    //setters & getters
}
```

Note the `@MapsId` annotation.

Comment: `@MapsId` applies to embeddables and not entities.

Comment: @AlvinThompson This should be valid, according to the JPA 2.1 spec, Section 2.4.1.3, Example 4, Case (b): "The dependent entity has a single primary key attribute corresponding to the relationship attribute. The primary key attribute is of the same basic type as the primary key of the parent entity. The MapsId annotation applied to the relationship attribute indicates that the primary key is mapped by the relationship attribute. "

Comment: If you edit your answer and give a quick working example I'll remove the down vote (I hate down voting).