# Why I get message on composite class?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I want to store user that was logged last time in a separate table. I created log_info table and for it **LogInfo** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="log_info")
public class LogInfo {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Accountant id;

    public LogInfo(){}

    public LogInfo(Accountant user){
        id = user;
    }

    public Accountant getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Accountant userId) {
        this.id = userId;
    }

}
```

My **Accountant** class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accountant")
public class Accountant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="accountant_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="mail")
    private String mail;

    @Column(name="avatar")
    private String avatar;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="interface_lang_id")
    private Languages interfaceCode;

    public Accountant(){}

    public Accountant(String name, String surname, String mail, String phone, Languages interfaceLang, String avatar){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.interfaceCode = interfaceLang;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Languages getInterfaceCode() {
        return interfaceCode;
    }

    public void setInterfaceCode(Languages interfaceCode) {
        this.interfaceCode = interfaceCode;
    }

}
```

This is database structure:

[image]

log_info table will always have just one record of user that was logged in last. When I tried running my app I got exception: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: home.accounting.model.LogInfo` Why I'm getting this exception even though I have only one column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276253/3959856

Comment: but I have only one `@Id`

Comment: Your Id column in `LogInfo` is of type `Accountant`

Comment: It shouldn't be? I thought it is how hibernate objects work

Comment: If you want it to be. It is composite key.. Maybe this explains it http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/

Comment: But in other classes I also have object reference, but don't have serialization, is it because of `@OneToOne` relationship?

Comment: No your `Id` column is a composite key. Maybe you don't need it to be? You could probably remove `@Id`. Id column is not necessary in this case I guess

Comment: But in Accountant class there is also a `Languages interfaceCode` why it is not counted as a composite?

Comment: Because it is not an identity field

Comment: I see now, got it

Comment: You know, everything that you said actually can be an answer, since it fully covers my question

Answer (score 0):

According to Hibernate documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite)

> The primary key class must be serializable.

It's defined by JPA specification.