# why primary key must implement Serializable interface in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Iam learning hibernate now. I came to know that when we need a composite primary key then we will put those variables inside one class which must implement serializable. when it comes to other than composite primary key i.e. single primary key of datatype primitives or Wrapper classes, these are directly or indirectly implementing serializable interfece. Upto here Iam ok,but my question is why we need to  implement serializable interface?? what is purpose of implementing serializable interface in hibernate??

Comment: What is your level of understanding of serialization? Maybe read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: @JohannesB I know if we implement serializable we can either store in file or send through the network.But what is the purpose of using it in hibernate??

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271835/why-composite-id-class-must-implement-serializable

Comment: @JohannesB.Finally i came to a conclusion after reading all links that session must be serialziable in hibernate and will get or update entity object by using primary key only.i.e PK column should be serialzable .Is that correct?? or do u have any other reasons??

Comment: That was my impression as well, probably because of second level cache APIs but doesn't it make a lot of sense that if you want to store Java objects frameworks rely on the Java standards like Serializable?

Comment: I think PK needs to be serializable because of just to make PK as a supertype of all.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the serializable interface with composite primary keys so you can uniquely identify an instance of the class that has the composite primary key.

The serializable interface allows hibernate to compare the object as a row in the database to all other rows in the database.

Consider the following kotlin entity class that represents the employee table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")

class Employee (

        @EmbeddedId
        var employeeKey: EmployeeKey
)
```

The `EmployeeKey` is a composite key class which looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
class EmployeeKey(

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        var firstName: String,

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        var lastName: String,

        @Column(name = "employee_id")
        var employeeId: Long

) : Serializable {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as EmployeeKey

        if (firstName != other.firstName) return false
        if (lastName != other.lastName) return false
        if (employeeId != employeeId) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = firstName.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + lastName.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + employeeId.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

The overridden methods define contracts for whether or not employee keys are equal to one another, as well as generating hash codes to uniquely identify each employee key on the hibernate side.